# Stripe set subscription to end on a particular date

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I have a subscription plan which I am initiating using stripe subscriptions.

It is billed monthly.
So if a person subscribed at 9 PM on Dec 7th, he/she should be able to use the product till the midnight of Jan 7th on the next cycle.

And then the cycle should keep on going for the next cycles as well.

My idea here is that, if a person subscribes to a product in the morning of a day, he/she should not get cancelled out towards the evening and all of the next month. He/She should probably get the entire day of their last cycle date.

And the same should be carried out for the next cycle as well.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. If you cannot do that, then the question is not on topic for StackOverflow but perhaps for SuperUser

Comment: When creating the subscription you can set the `billing_cycle_anchor` to be an arbitrary timestamp (like midnight): https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-billing_cycle_anchor